# UIDocumentInteractionController not showing .docx apps like Word and Pages

Tags: ios, swift, document, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I have a chat app that also lets you send and receive documents. I'd like to be able to open .docx files in a suitable app like Word or Pages.

The code I'm currently using:

```swift
self.uidic = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
self.uidic?.delegate = self
_ = self.uidic?.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.bounds, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

Now the picker pops up but doesn't show the right apps:

[image]

This is on simulator but on my device it also shows Airdrop, Notes and even Facebook. However no Word and no Pages, which are installed.

Same issue with PDFs: I have Adobe Acrobat installed but it's not showing.

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently http urls don't work like this.

My first solution was to just pass the url to Safari and let it sort it out, which works ok.

Now I download the file first to the documents folder, then use its local url and it shows the appropriate apps fine.